# Image Location?

Tags: image, location

I am having trouble simply importing an image using this code. Where should the Image be stored? I thought it had to be in a folder within the source folder and in this case called ImageIcon but I am not sure... thanks to anybody who helps!

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    class Surface extends JPanel {

    private Image mshi;

    public Surface() {

        loadImage();
        setSurfaceSize();
    }

    private void loadImage() {

        mshi = new ImageIcon("mushrooms.jpg").getImage();
    }

    private void setSurfaceSize() {

        Dimension d = new Dimension();
        d.width = mshi.getWidth(null);
        d.height = mshi.getHeight(null);
        setPreferredSize(d);        
    }

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(mshi, 1, 1, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }
}

public class DisplayImage extends JFrame {

    public DisplayImage() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setTitle("Mushrooms");

        add(new Surface());

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DisplayImage ex = new DisplayImage();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to put the image in the same directory as your class file Surface ?

Comment: right now I have it in the build folder it is beside the surface class file. where should I move it from here? I cannot open the class surface... is that a possible issue?

Comment: I don't understand why you can not open the class Surface ? The code you posted is located in which file ? Sorry i don't have my computer right now to test your code and for my english, it still under construction.

Comment: And i think it is better to put your image file in a directory other than your source file (Surface). Create a directory like images at the same level of your source directory.

Comment: the class is called DisplayImage  and so how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry i had not seen the class DisplayImage.

The best way i think to do it, create a separate class file for Surface.
Write in Surface class file, a constructor with parameter. The parameter will be the image path. It will be simple for you to change the image if you want after.

Something like this :

```
public class Surface extends JPanel {
    private Image mshi;

    public Surface(String imagePath) {

        mshi = new ImageIcon(imagePath).getImage();

        setSurfaceSize();
    }

    private void setSurfaceSize() {

        Dimension d = new Dimension();
        d.width = mshi.getWidth(null);
        d.height = mshi.getHeight(null);
        setPreferredSize(d);        
    }

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(mshi, 1, 1, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }
```

}

You don't need to write the method loadImage(), it will be probably used in your class because it is private and it just do one simple thing.

Concerning the structure of your project directory make something like this

Project directory\src

Project directory\src\Surface.class

Project directory\src\DisplayImage.class

Project directory\images

Project directory\images\mushrooms.jpg

Ps : Sorry for my english, it still under construction.